# Why we are using PT1 Damping in automobile Sensor values?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, sensors, data, calibration

I got to know that most of the automobile manufactures are using PT1 Damping (concept like `raising Linear`/ `PT1 failing time` etc. ) algorithm in their `sensor values`.

**For example :**

1. PT1 damping is used in `ABS Sensor value` to determine the `speed`.
2. PT1 damping is used in `thermometer sensor value` to determine the `temperature`.

I know that sampling is required to get the average values from the sensor. But i don't understand why we required to use `Damping algorithms (PT1 damping)` for sensor values?
If anybody has any reference of PT1 damping, Please suggest some useful links. So that i can understand more about that concept.

Comment: I haven't really heard the term "PT1", but a [quick search](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibbabasic/html/TcPlcLibBABasic_PT1.htm&id=) says it's just a first-order low-pass, pretty much the simplest type of filter. It is straightforward to implement digitally as an IIR filter, like  y[n] = (1-a)x[n] + (a)y[n-1]  where a is calculated from the desired corner frequency. Being a first order LPF, it avoids numerical issues that can happen when implementing higher order digital filters.